# WCF Multiple Services with DataContracts as Parameters C#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datacontract

I have multiple `DataContracts` and the same number of WCF Services to manage methods for each one. I have a specific `[DataContract]` called `User` that I use as paramenter in every other service, for example: `ListCompany(User, CompanyId)`.

When a make  a service referece to the WCF service, Company, it has a `[DataContract] User` too like `Company.User` which is different from the original `User`. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

### Logically Same DataContract, Used in Multiple Services

You are probably adding service references in the usual way for a WCF service client using the *Add Service Reference...* menu option. When you do that, a `Reference.cs` file will be generated for each service, and each service will have a different namespace. However, since you're sharing contracts across services, you need to click the Advanced... button on the **Add Service Reference** dialog and make sure the *Reuse types in referenced assemblies* is checked and (easiest) make sure *Reuse types in all referenced assemblies* is checked.

Now, that will not work if you don't actually have normal project or assembly references to the assemblies that contain those `[DataContract]` classes. So, add those references. If those classes are mixed into your server-side implementation, you will need to move them to their own assemblies and reference them on both the client and server.

### Logically Different DataContract, Used in Multilpe Services

If you really have two different types of users (i.e. two different contracts) where you are using one contract for one service client and one contract for another service client, you should make sure Reuse types in referenced assemblies is not checked, and make sure that each service reference is in a different namespace.

An alternative is using a different name for each when declaring them:

```
[DataContract(Name = "User"]
public class User { ... }

[DataContract(Name = "CompanyUser")]
public class User { .... }
```

The code above assumes each `User` class is in a different server-side namespace, possibly different assembly as well.

Comment: Obviously make sure you reference the DataContract assembly and most of this will just happen automatically from there.

Comment: that checkbox ought to be on by default, BTW, assuming you have the types in a properly referenced assembly.

Comment: I have something like this:   [DataContract(Name = "User")]  so i have a WCF Service called User, i have [DataContract (Name = "Company"] and also the WCF Service Comapany, they are both int the same class library, Company have a method ListCompany(User, Id) - USER is the real USER datacontract as parameter, when i call Company WCF service i need to pass a USER a parameter but i can not use the original USER i can only usye Company.User. Is this default when we create separeted DataContracts and WCF Services?

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. Do you have a service named `User` and a class named `USER`? I think you may want to re-edit your question and add some code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should look into a better way to use your WCF services that adding service references. This golden article describes how you can share the data contracts between all your solutions, and make use of them by using Chanel factories, without having VS generate loads of code for you.  http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2008/11/understanding-wcf-services-in-silverlight-2

It might seem like a lot to take in, but it's full of really useful tips, including *Service Access without magic* which goes like this:

> Now we may turn our attention to the client application.  To begin,
>   let me start off by reminding everyone that you shouldn't ever use
>   "Add Service Reference" in Visual Studio for magical service client
>   creation.  The code is incredibly verbose, hard to manageable, edits
>   are prone to being overwritten, and it's almost always used as an
>   excuse to not actually learn WCF.  There are few things worse than
>   having to deal with people who thing they know a product simply
>   because they know how to use a mouse.  There are reasons why Juval
>   Lowy, in all his books and talks, repeatedly tells people to avoid
>   using this flawed feature.  Fortunately, as professionals, we have the
>   ability to understand how to do things without magic.
>
> As I've mentioned many times already, WCF relies on the concept of the
>   ABC.  We've seen how we configure a WCF host by creating an endpoint
>   specifying an address, binding and contract.  As it turns out, this is
>   all that's required on the client side as well.  For both .NET and
>   Silverlight, you merge an address and a binding with a contract in a
>   channel factory to create a channel.  This isn't just fancy conceptual
>   architect speak, this is exactly what your code would look like (the
>   sign of really good architecture!)  Below is the .NET version of what
>   I mean:

```
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:1003/Person.svc");
    IPersonService personService = new ChannelFactory<IPersonService>(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress).CreateChannel();
    //+
    Person person = personService.GetPersonData("F488D20B-FC27-4631-9FB9-83AF616AB5A6");
```

Well worth a read.